# Android "spotlight" with changing shader

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I used the following example to create a spotlight shader: http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/13/android-recipe-2-fun-with-shaders/

It works great and I use the spotlight with `HorizontalScrollView` and now I have to scroll the `HorizontalScrollView` at the same time I move the mask, and I can't figure out how to get it to work with good performance. The `HorizontalScrollView` has like 5 times screen width of content, and the `Shader` bitmap is only one screen width. Setting it all again when scrolling is too heavy operation and eventually causes memory crashes.

Thanks.

The picture below is to demonstrate my setting. I have A and B stacked on `FrameLayout`. While A moves the spotlight B scrolls the content. So could A somehow draw the spotlight as a "transparent hole" in it's background? A is `Fragment` pager which moves the spotlight and scrolls B `ScrollView` at the same time.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure but maybe animations is not the best way to do what you're doing? Wouldn't it be better to create an image "transparent hole" and use it, still pass touch events to your scrollview, and play with the image as needed for more complex shading.

Comment: I am not running any animations here, I could use transparent hole image, which would be so big that the "hole" could be in any position of the screen. Problem there, is that I want the "hole" be 80% width of the screen, so with that solution I cant scale the image and so on the get the hole proper size.

Comment: I am really sorry but can you please explain further what the problem is? You have this spotlight view above your scroll container. You want the container to scroll when touched (appropriately). But? I do not think you need a big shader because in its worst case, the shader needs to occupy one screen.

Comment: I updated the description, the B container gets scrolled when Pager is scrolled to change it's Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any of the code you are using it is a bit hard to help you improve performance, but I have two suggestions:

You write *"Setting it all again when scrolling is too heavy operation and eventually causes memory crashes"*. I assume you are reloading the `Bitmap` at times. This is not a good idea, since it causes the problems you describe. Instead create it only once and transform using the various bitmap methods.

Secondly, if you don't have very advanced content in the `ScrollView`, consider combining the scrolling content with the spotlight-effect in a `SurfaceView` and manually draw everything on a Canvas.

On a final note, you also write that you are using a `FragmentPager` for moving the spotlight. This does not seem like the most optimal way, consider whether the result you want must be achieved this way.

Comment: The code is in the Romain Guys example how I use the spotlight mask. As said it's designed for static view to mask. So if I would use that, I need to reload the bitmap mask all the time, because the container B ScrollView moves when scrolling the pager. I don't see any code posting relevant, because it's all explained how my setting works. The content in ScrollView is advanced custom view with many layers. Maybe moving the spotlight isn't optimal, but theres no performance issues seen yet. It is designed this way and I implemented it, and then came up with this problem I posted.

Comment: I'm looking the answer how to use spotlight when the target that it's masking changes all the time.

Comment: Why would you write "but theres no performance issues seen yet" when you in you question you clearly state "I can't figure out how to get it to work with good performance"?  
You'll also find that most people here don't want to download external files just to see the code they are going to help with.

Comment: Have you tried to call `invalidate()` on your spotlightview when the  background view changes?

Comment: No perfomance issues when the mask bitmap is static content, so the mask moving itself is not heavy operation when using with example code. Have you checked the example code? You use the mask by setting a target bitmap, and the issue is that my target bitmap changes all the time, so I would have to call that code all the time which is heavy and cannot use it like that.